# How should I test this, do I mock since it is hitting the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a method that does this:

Given a array of tags, it tries to fetch the Tag by its name from the db if it exists, otherwise it creates a new Tag.   It then returns a collection of all the tag objects.

```
tag_text = "general tag1 tag2"
```

the Tag.rb model has a name property that would be in the db if it exists.

How should I go about testing the method:

```
 def find_tags_from_tag_text (tag_text)

          tags = []

          tag_text.split.each do |x|
               t = Tag.find_by_name(x)

               if t.nil?  
                 t = Tag.new(name => x).save!
               end

               tags << t

          end

    end
```

Comment: Can you just write a unit test that calls this method with two tags - one already in the DB, and one not - and wrap it in an [assert_difference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_difference) block, to make sure that exactly one new tag is created?  And as an aside:  [find_or_create](http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/lianaleahy/2008/05/19/find_or_create/) might save you a bit of typing here.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Rails testing guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html covers pretty much what you are trying to do, have you checked it out? TL;DR: 1) prepare fixtures - data to initialize blank testing database with, 2) write tests to compare actual results with expected results of your model's methods.

Comment: I wanted to do a unit test, not a integration test, so I thought I'd have to mock.  isn't that the purist way of doing it? seperate unit testing from integration testing.